# SQL queries in Case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a  table named tblAccount where I have two columns:

1. DateCreated
2. AccountApprovalDate

DateCreated is the date on which the account is created and AccountApprovalDate is the date on which the account is approved.

I need to create a column named 'AccountApproval/RejectDate'. Here the Reject Date is a derived value.(i.e).There is a table named tblDeclinedaccounts,When accountId is there in this table then select the DateCRetaed column.
 This column can have only approval date or reject date.
When AccountApprovalDate is not null, then the value is same. and when reject date is not null then we need to select Datecreated column.
 i wrote the following query:

```
SELECT AC.Datecreated, 'Approved/Rejected Date' =
    CASE
        WHEN AC.AccountApprovalDate IS NOT NULL THEN 
            (SELECT AC.AccountApprovalDate)
        WHEN AC.AccountApprovalDate IS NULL THEN 
            (SELECT DA.Datecreated 
             FROM tblDeclinedAccounts DA 
             INNER JOIN tblAccount AC ON DA.AccountID = AC.AccountID where DA.AccountID IS NOT NULL)

    END
FROM tblAccount AC
```

I got error on executing:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

This needs to be a sub query.

Comment: "This needs to be a sub query!" - I think you'll find a join is possible....

Comment: Well clearly the issue is that `tblDeclinedAccounts` has multiple rows for at least one account. How do you want that scenario handled?

Comment: You can ADD top(1) in your subquery but there is better answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why does it need to be a subquery? Just join and use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT ac.accountid, COALESCE(ac.approvaldate, da.datecreated) as 'Approved/Rejected Date'
FROM tblAccount ac
JOIN tblDeclinedAccounts da
ON da.Accountid = ac.Accountid;
```

Comment: Thanks veredesmarald,I just made a minor mistake but this query works..:)Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

@veredesmarald is already correct.

Here is an alternative.

```
SELECT ac.accountid, IsNull(ac.approvaldate, da.datecreated) as 'Approved/Rejected Date'
FROM tblAccount ac
JOIN tblDeclinedAccounts da
ON da.Accountid = ac.Accountid;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MIN` or `MAX` to ensure that rejection date is unique.

```
SELECT AC.DateCreated
    , COALESCE(R.RejectionDate, AC.AccountApprovalDate) [Approved/Rejected Date]
FROM tblAccount AC
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT AccountID, MIN(DateCreated) RejectionDate
    FROM tblDeclinedAccounts
    GROUP BY DateCreated
) AS R ON R.AccountID = AC.AccountID
```

Comment: When i run this query, if ACcountApprovalDate is present,then it selects that date else if AccountApprovalDAte is null,instead of selecting the dtaecreated column,it is still showing null

Comment: Good point. The coalesce args were the wrong way round. I have edited my answer.